# Chrome Extension XMLHttpRequest Can't open same-window link

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am making a chrome extension for a scraper im Working on to control it etc.. I Have a login script which is here:

```
<?php

    $username = $_GET['username'];
    $password = $_GET['password'];

    $pass = sha1($password);

    $mysql = new mysqli("*" , "*" , "!!*" , "*");

    $data = $mysql->query("SELECT * FROM `staff_section`.`logins` WHERE `staff_name` = '$username' && `staff_pass` = '$pass'");

    echo $data->num_rows;

    $mysql->close();
    unset($data);

?>
```

And I Have my Launch.js File here:

```
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function(){
        chrome.app.window.create('window.html' , {
            'outerBounds': {
                'width' : 720,
                'height' : 720
            } , 
            frame: 'none'
        });
        get("loginform").addEventListener('submit' , function(){
            checkLogin(get("username").value , get("password").value);
        });
});
function checkSession(){
        if(Session.getSession("authorized") == false){
            //Do nothing
        }else{

        }
        }
        function checkLogin(username , password){
            var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlhttp.open("get" , "http://192.168.4.240/CHROME_APP_SERVER/ajax/login.php?username=" + username + "&password=" + password , false);
            xmlhttp.send();
            if(xmlhttp.responseText == "1"){
                Session.start();

            }else{
                alert("Incorrect Credentials");
            }
        }
        function get(id){
            return document.getElementById(id);
        }
```

And my Window.html file here:

```
<html>
    <title></title>
    <script src="js/launch.js"></script>
    <script src="js/session.js"></script>
    <style>

    </style>

<body bgcolor="#404040">
    <div style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;width:100%;height:50px;background:#171717;">
        <img src="img/jejamesicon.ico" style="position:absolute;top:10px;left:10px;" width="30" height="30"/>
        <p style="position:absolute;top:17.5px;left:55px;color:#fff;font-family:verdana;margin:0px;"></p>
    </div>
    <div style="position:absolute;top:60px;left:10px;right:10px;bottom:10px;text-align:center;">
        <form id="loginform">
            <input type="text" id="username" placeholder="Username"/>
            <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="Password"/>
            <input type="submit" value="Log In"/>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

When I try making the login XMLHttpRequest All I get is:

```
  Can't open same-window link to "chrome-extension://iflddlelmkkkeoehpghlblcmkkbgacpp/window.html?"; try target="_blank".
```

Why cant I make XMLHttpRequests? I have set the Permission in the Manifest:

```
{
    "manifest_version" : 2,
    "name": "J E James Scraper",
    "description" : "J E James Cycles Scraper GUI",
    "version" : "1.0",
    "app" : {
        "background" : {
            "scripts" : ["js/launch.js"]
        }
    },
    "icons" : {
        "128" : "img/icon.png"
    } , 
    "permissions" : [
        "http://192.168.4.240/*"
    ]
}
```

So why isnt My Scraper Working, the login script is stored on the specified url above

Comment: `checkLogin` and `get` functions are in different scope and can't be visible in `onLaunched.addListener`. Is this because you reformatted the code to shorten it? If so, edit it, please.

Comment: Thanks , Just realised that I feel such an Idiot

Comment: Eh? So that fixed the issue? We need to close the question then.

Comment: Yeah , But It was still a Valid Question